# Reading a json file using php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to read a special json file with php. This is the file:

```
[
 [
   {
   "Programpart": "Ball", 
   "version": "0.5.1", 
   "date": "2014-06-01" ,
   "file_name":"MyProgram-0.5.1",
   "name":"MyProgram",
   "author":"Peter",
   }
 ]
 ,
  [
   {
   "Programpart": "Court", 
   "version": "0.5.2", 
   "date": "2014-06-02" ,
   "file_name":"MyProgram-0.5.2",
   "name":"MyProgram",
   "author":"Peter",
   }
 ]
]
```

My problem is, that the objects and arrays have no names. I did it with a simple standard json file, but I couldn't do it with this one. I need to get all the values for "Programpart" and the corresponding values for "version".
How can I do this?

I know there have been similar questions, but I have tried a bunch of things and still couldn't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '[
 [
   {
   "Programpart": "Ball", 
   "version": "0.5.1", 
   "date": "2014-06-01" ,
   "file_name":"MyProgram-0.5.1",
   "name":"MyProgram",
   "author":"Peter"
   }
 ]
 ,
  [
   {
   "Programpart": "Court", 
   "version": "0.5.2", 
   "date": "2014-06-02" ,
   "file_name":"MyProgram-0.5.2",
   "name":"MyProgram",
   "author":"Peter"
   }
 ]
]';

$json = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($json as $outer_array) {
    foreach ($outer_array as $inner_array) {
        echo $inner_array['Programpart'].' = '.$inner_array['version'];
    }

}
```

Try that - I had to remove the trailing commas at the end of the author line.

Comment: Glad it works.  Could you accept the answer please - click the tick!?